# gedit External Tools & Csound

Tags: gedit

I am a newbie at Linux and so far so good my workflow of studying music with Csound is adding a new tool under the External Tools Gedit plugin doing this,

```
#!/bin/sh
csound '/home/ye53b/Desktop/TC4R37A7B/music/csound'
```

which is a text file containing the Csound syntax that later is interpreted as noise...

Is there any way to identify the path of the file I am in, instead of using a main text file every time (`/home/ye53b/Desktop/TC4R37A7B/music/csound`)?

Answer (score 0):

I got it using this (it is a variable from the [plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools))

```
#!/bin/sh
csound $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
```